# Freezing partially cooked hamburger patties

Tags: beef, ground

I want to make a large batch of hamburger patties from frozen ground beef (thawed properly).  My question is, can I partially cook then freeze?

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to come up with a protocol to do this safely, however the more time that meat spends in the so-called thermal danger zone the more you need to thoroughly cook it at the end. It's hard to understand what you would be gaining by doing this.

Comment: I agree, you could do this but it isn't likely to lead to tasty burgers.

Comment: If you had meat with a more well-defined surface such as filet of beef you could argue that partially precooking after properly thawing in a cold environment would kill bacteria on the surface while allowing you to properly cook in a frying pan or oven rather than overcooking an already finished product in a microwave oven. There would stil be a balance between that method and the longer time spent at higher temperature.